# Spacing before Chapter not removeable using titlesec

Tags: spacing, koma-script, chapters, titlesec, scrreprt

I am trying to remove the spacing before the chapter. I have found several solutions using titlesec. Whenever I use such solutions I get errors of missing numbers and illegal units of measures for \section.

Since I am just working myself into using LaTeX I don't have a good understanding about the packages and how they affect each other.

This is what I have tried

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{titlesec}

% this isn't working
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{0pt}{40pt}

\begin{document}
    \blinddocument
\end{document}
```

So what is a good way to reduce the spacing before the chapters?

Comment: Off topic: Load `hyperref` after your other packages. `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc` is not needed with an uptodate TeX distribution. Do not change `\parskip` and `\parindent` manually. You could use KOMA-Script option `parskip=half` or `\parskip=half-`  or `\parskip=full`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`titlesec` is incompatible with KOMA-classes (like `scrreprt` you're using), but you can adjust the spacing with `\RedeclareSectionCommand` instead:

```
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip = 0pt,afterindent=false]{chapter}
```

For a more detailed explanation on how to change chapter/section formats, have a look at section 21.8. of the KOMA manual ([en](https://mirror.kumi.systems/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf) [de](https://mirror.kumi.systems/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguide.pdf)).

Comment: Thank you, I'll read the documentation, works like a charm, Upvote will come soon :)

Comment: Alternatively, you could stick with `titlesec` and not use `scrreprt` instead.